# GraphQL error Cannot perform update query

Tags: node.js, graphql

I'm working on a ToDo list application in NodeJS, Koa, and GraphQL.
I wrote an update card mutation but when I run the query to update I get the following error:

```
Cannot perform update query because update values are not defined. Call "qb.set(...)" method to specify updated values.
```

The mutation:

```
import { getRepository } from 'typeorm';
import { Card } from '../../entities/card';

export const updateCardMutation = {
    async updateCard(_, { id, patch }): Promise<Card> {
        const repository = getRepository(Card);
        const card = await repository.findOne({ id });
        const result = await repository.update(id, patch);
        return {
            ...card,
            ...patch,
        };
    },
};
```

I would like to know what I'm doing wrong and if something more is needed it please notify me so I will edit the question accordingly

card entity:

```
import { Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column, CreateDateColumn, UpdateDateColumn } from 'typeorm';

@Entity('cards')
export class Card {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
    id: string;

    @CreateDateColumn()
    created_at: Date;

    @UpdateDateColumn()
    updated_at: Date;

    @Column('text')
    title: string;

    @Column('text', {
        nullable: true,
    })
    description: string;

    @Column('boolean', {
        default: 'false',
    })
    done: boolean;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to spread the update Object.

```
export const updateCardMutation = {
async updateCard(_, { id, patch }): Promise<Card> {
    const repository = getRepository(Card);
    const card = await repository.findOne({ id });
    const result = await repository.update(id, {...patch}); // here
    return {
        ...card,
        ...patch,
    };
},
```

};

Answer (score 1):

The issue was when I was calling the `updateMutation`, it was creating the patch object of anonymous type. So it just needed to be clean before going to the DB engine

I resolved my issues by adding the following code:

```
{ ...patch }
```

Inside the next script:

```
export const updateCardMutation = {
    async updateCard(_, { id, patch }): Promise<Card> {
        const repository = getRepository(Card);
        const card = await repository.findOne({ id });
        const result = await repository.update(id, { ...patch }); // Added here
        return {
            ...card,
            ...patch,
        };
    },
};
```

In this way, I was able to update my card.

Answer (score 1):

I have had this error before with my update query is `nestjs` & `graqhql`

> Cannot perform update query because update values are not defined

I have fixed it by using the **save()** function from the repository on the same id, so I have changed from this

```
async update(
    id: number,
    updateEmployeeInput: UpdateEmployeeInput,
  ): Promise<Employee> {
    await this.employeeRepository.update(id, updateEmployeeInput);
    return this.employeeRepository.findOneOrFail(id);
  }
```

to this

```
async update(
    id: number,
    updateEmployeeInput: UpdateEmployeeInput,
  ): Promise<Employee> {
    await this.employeeRepository.save(updateEmployeeInput)
    return this.employeeRepository.findOneOrFail(id);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/update-query-builder.md

As an error Call qb.set() , typeorm query builder are different with other orm

```
await getRepository().createQueryBuilder().update(Card).set(patch)
.where("id = :id", { id })
.execute();
```

some how patch object may stringify [object], so you can spread it like set({...patch})

Comment: Unfortunate this is giving the same error as before and no changes

Comment: i also suggested you spreading object , but this was an second option